# starting flask with env variable from separate config file still starts in production

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a separate file called config.py, in it I have my environment classes, then I import to python, set the config file to app.config using the from_object method, but when I call flask run it still says production even though debug mode is set to true.

```
from flask import Flask
from config import DevConfig

 app = Flask(__name__)
 app.config.from_object(DevConfig)
 print(DevConfig.DEBUG)
 @app.route('/')
 def home():
    return '<h1>Hello World</h1>'

 if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run()
```

config.py

```
class Config(object):
    pass

class ProdConfig(Config):
    pass
class DevConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True
```

result

```
 * Serving Flask app "main.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
True
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Flask documentation for Builtin configuration values](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/#builtin-configuration-values):

> The env attribute maps to this config key. This is set by the
>   FLASK_ENV environment variable and may not behave as expected if set
>   in code.

The [configuration best practices documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/?highlight=app%20config%20from_object#configuration-best-practices) shows an example of using multiple configurations for different environment.

Following the documentation, I got `Debug mode: on` but the environment is still shown as `production`.

Folder structure:

```
.
├── app.py
└── configurations.py
```

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from configurations import DevelopmentConfig


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(DevelopmentConfig)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return '<h1>Hello World</h1>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

`configurations.py`:

```
class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False

class ProductionConfig(Config):
    pass

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True

class TestingConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True
```

Running the app:

```
(venv) python app.py
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 312-674-275
127.0.0.1 - - [18/May/2019 23:10:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Installed packages:

```
Click==7.0
Flask==1.0.3
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
pkg-resources==0.0.0
Werkzeug==0.15.4
```

As `debug` mode is `on`, the app runs in development environment. But Flask documentation suggests to use `flask` method to run the project.

To switch Flask to the development environment and enable debug mode, set `FLASK_ENV`:

```
$ export FLASK_ENV=development
$ flask run
```

(On Windows, use `set` instead of `export`.)

From [Flask doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/server/#server):

> Example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

> This works well for the common case but it does not work well for development which is why from Flask 0.11 onwards the flask
>   method is recommended. The reason for this is that due to how the
>   reload mechanism works there are some bizarre side-effects (like
>   executing certain code twice, sometimes crashing without message or
>   dying when a syntax or import error happens).

Comment: thanks the tutorial didnt mention passing the export FLASK_ENV=development